# delphi mergesort for string arrays

Tags: algorithm, delphi, delphi-7, pascal, mergesort

Found this coded mergesort on http://www.explainth.at/en/delphi/dsort.shtml (site down but try wayback machine or this site: http://read.pudn.com/downloads192/sourcecode/delphi_control/901147/Sorts.pas__.htm) but essentially the array defined was not for an array of string.
`type TSortArray = array[0..8191] of Double;`
I want to pass an array of string that would possibly eliminate duplicates (this would be Union?) *and preserve original order if possible for later resorting it back to original index position minus the duplicates of course (original index)* so array can be passed back for further processing. I am using very large files of strings with millions of strings (14 to 30 million) so `TStringList` is not an option. Best option for these large files is to use arrays of string or arrays of records (or maybe single linked list??) and sort with stable algorithm made for large amount of data.

1. How can I change this to take array of string?
2. How can it be further modified to delete or at least mark duplicates?
3. Is it possible to store original index number to place back strings in original position?
4. Are arrays of string or arrays of record better for large number of strings as compared to a single linked list?

Questions are listed in order of importance so if you answer question number 1 only that is fine. Thank you in advance for all your input.

---

```
procedure MergeSort(var Vals:TSortArray;ACount:Integer);
var AVals:TSortArray;

  procedure Merge(ALo,AMid,AHi:Integer);
  var i,j,k,m:Integer;
  begin
    i:=0;
    for j:=ALo to AMid do
    begin
      AVals[i]:=Vals[j];
      inc(i);
      //copy lower half or Vals into temporary array AVals
    end;

    i:=0;j:=AMid + 1;k:=ALo;//j could be undefined after the for loop!
    while ((k < j) and (j <= AHi)) do
    if (AVals[i] < Vals[j]) then
    begin
      Vals[k]:=AVals[i];
      inc(i);inc(k);
    end else
    begin
      Vals[k]:=Vals[j];
      inc(k);inc(j);
    end;
    {locate next greatest value in Vals or AVals and copy it to the
     right position.}

    for m:=k to j - 1 do
    begin
      Vals[m]:=AVals[i];
      inc(i);
    end;
    //copy back any remaining, unsorted, elements
  end;

  procedure PerformMergeSort(ALo,AHi:Integer);
  var AMid:Integer;
  begin
    if (ALo < AHi) then
    begin
      AMid:=(ALo + AHi) shr 1;
      PerformMergeSort(ALo,AMid);
      PerformMergeSort(AMid + 1,AHi);
      Merge(ALo,AMid,AHi);   <==== passing the array as string causes AV breakdown here
    end;
  end;

begin
  SetLength(AVals, ACount);
  PerformMergeSort(0,ACount - 1);
end;
```

Comment: You have neglected to ask a question.

Comment: @RobKennedy Thank you and updated accordingly.

Comment: Why TStringList is not an option, but array of string is used? Would you think about databases?

Comment: @MBo, as TStringList actually uses an array of string internally (well, sort of).

Comment: TStringList would use quicksort (at least with fpc), which is not stable.  Although I'm not sure, why you want a stable sort here. I guess there is either an index error (try to run it with range checking and on a double-array of the same size), or you run out of memory with all these strings (15 million, perhaps 1000 letters in each => almost 14 GB required).

Comment: Now you've asked 4 questions!

Comment: @all TStringList or even TList derived object simply does not handle the volume of strings. Frequently the files are 2 GB or more and I simply have total of 4GB of ram. I tried TStringList multiple times and on 600mb file it works fine. As the files get larger TStringList becomes a very bad option. Arrays of string work extremely well and mergesort is very good at handling extremely large arrays. What I did not try is Linked lists but I think arrays probably are more efficient than even single linked lists. Hope this clarifies my thinking.

Comment: You can't use array of string or another data structures for in-memory sorting files > 2GB both in 32-bit Windows and with 32-bit version of Delphi (tag "Delphi 7"). Yo need some kind of external sort routine (usually based on mergesort) in this case or use database approach

Comment: Exactly. Your problem is not that your mergesort is broken, but that your entire design is broken. You can't even load the data into memory so there's little point in continuing with your current approach.

Comment: I did try the above merge sort with a very small size file less than 100mb as a testing case and it doesn't work as is. I don't know if freepascal runs it and it may run it as is for strings after passing the right type of course : `type TSortArray = array of string;` but delphi does not. I never programmed databases so it is likely not my first option right now, although it would be nice to learn more about it. I did use mergesort on large files and although it was slow in my opinion, it worked without running out of memory.

Comment: Why the down vote? good thing I didn't ask about timsort implementation then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to the second question: Mergesort modification with duplicate deleting. Should work for strings.

```
//returns new valid length
function MergeSortRemoveDuplicates(var Vals: array of Integer):Integer;
var
  AVals: array of Integer;

   //returns index of the last valid element
  function Merge(I0, I1, J0, J1: Integer):Integer;
  var
    i, j, k, LC:Integer;
  begin
    LC := I1 - I0;
    for i := 0 to LC do
      AVals[i]:=Vals[i + I0];
      //copy lower half or Vals into temporary array AVals

    k := I0;
    i := 0;
    j := J0;
    while ((i <= LC) and (j <= J1)) do
    if (AVals[i] < Vals[j]) then begin
      Vals[k] := AVals[i];
      inc(i);
      inc(k);
    end else  if (AVals[i] > Vals[j]) then begin
      Vals[k]:=Vals[j];
      inc(k);
      inc(j);
    end else begin //duplicate
      Vals[k] := AVals[i];
      inc(i);
      inc(j);
      inc(k);
    end;

    //copy the rest
    while i <= LC do begin
      Vals[k] := AVals[i];
      inc(i);
      inc(k);
    end;

    if k <> j then
      while j <= J1 do begin
        Vals[k]:=Vals[j];
        inc(k);
        inc(j);
      end;

    Result := k - 1;
  end;

 //returns index of the last valid element

  function PerformMergeSort(ALo, AHi:Integer): Integer; //returns
  var
    AMid, I1, J1:Integer;
  begin

  //It would be wise to use Insertion Sort when (AHi - ALo) is small (about 32-100)
    if (ALo < AHi) then
    begin
      AMid:=(ALo + AHi) shr 1;
      I1 := PerformMergeSort(ALo, AMid);
      J1 := PerformMergeSort(AMid + 1, AHi);
      Result := Merge(ALo, I1, AMid + 1, J1);
    end else
      Result := ALo;
  end;

begin
  SetLength(AVals, Length(Vals) div 2 + 1);
  Result := 1 + PerformMergeSort(0, High(Vals));
end;


//short test
var
  A: array of Integer;
  i, NewLen: Integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  SetLength(A, 12);
  for i := 0 to High(A) do
    A[i] := Random(10);
   NewLen := MergeSortRemoveDuplicates(A);
   SetLength(A, NewLen);
   for i := 0 to High(A) do
     Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(A[i]))
  end;
```

Simple modification for strings:

```
function MergeSortRemoveDuplicates(var Vals: array of String):Integer;
var
  AVals: array of String;
```

and test case:

```
var
  List: TStringList;
  Arr: array of string;
  i, n: Integer;
begin
  with TStringList.Create do try
    LoadFromFile('F:\m2.txt'); //contains some equal strings
    SetLength(Arr, Count);
    for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
      Arr[i] := Strings[i];
  finally
    Free
  end;
  n := MergeSortRemoveDuplicates(Arr);
  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Arr[i]);
end;
```

Comment: this is great if you can pass strings to it. The problem is that even your test case is integers. Thank you.

Comment: I see no problem with so simple modification. Added.

Comment: Thank you. I think I see the problem I'm having: my strings are not equal in length or even character set at times. Thank you again.

Comment: works fantastic. disregard my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

1. You'd need to modify the declaration TSortArray from array of double to array of string (or array of MyRecord)

   The comparison routines in the Merge nested proc needs to be made compatible for strings. Check for anywhere that determines whether AVal[x] < / > AVal[y]. Delphi has procedures for this (AnsiCompareText / AnsiCompareStr depending on whether you want case-sensitivity)

   That *should* work, but if you hadn't done this in your earlier attempts then Delphi should have complained about type mismatches rather than giving an AV, so there may be something else going on
2. I think duplicate checking should be done post-sort - it only requires one scan through of the data
3. If you want to store original index data then you will probably need to use an array of record (data: string; OriginalIndex: integer). Code in the Merge procedure then needs to be modified to pass Vals[x].Data to comparison routines. Filling the OriginalIndex values will be a quick scan before calling the Merge procedure
4. Not 100% sure, to be honest - it's easier to move large contiguous chunks of data with linked lists than with arrays, and arrays don't need messing about with pointers. If your dataset is sufficiently large you may even need to resort to streaming to disk which is likely to drive your choice more than either of those points.

Comment: Of course - as MBo says in comments, inserting all your data into a database as records (Data / OriginalOrder) then sorting with a 'Select * From Table OrderBy Data' query and iterating over the results is probably far easier

Comment: This looks like the most complete answer. Can you show me what you mean by the modifications on mergesort?

Comment: apparently I can pick only one answer. I think your answer is also great and it covers all my questions.