# Dissecting mergesort routine

Tags: algorithm, delphi, sorting, computer-science, mergesort

**Disclaimer:** this is a question that requires some explanation of code and algorithm. It is not intended to fix anything or optimize anything but rather facilitate understanding.

My understanding of sorting routines is not great. I asked for help with converting an already available code for mergesort from `integer type` to `string type` here: [delphi mergesort for string arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673633/delphi-mergesort-for-string-arrays). After I received my answer I set out to understand the sorting routine.

Couple of resources came handy to help understanding:

1. http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/merge/mergen.htm
2. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Qk1t66g7IU

I attempted to dissect the code to follow it along. This question is not my attempt to validate my own understanding of mergesort, but rather show the sorting routine in a clear manner. The value of this question is for people attempting to understand mergesort better. This is essential as other sorts can be understood easier if you understand one prototype well.

**My question is why did we add "1" to set length and to "Result"**

```
SetLength(AVals, Length(Vals) div 2 + 1);
Result := 1 + PerformMergeSort(0, High(Vals));
```

**and why did we subtract "1" here?** *EDIT: I think K will be out of bounds if not subtract 1?*

```
Result := k - 1;
```

here is the code in this question; BTW this is an optimized mergesort as it copies only half the array:

```
function MergeSortRemoveDuplicates(var Vals: array of Integer):Integer;
var
  AVals: array of Integer;

   //returns index of the last valid element
  function Merge(I0, I1, J0, J1: Integer):Integer;
  var
    i, j, k, LC:Integer;
  begin
    LC := I1 - I0;
    for i := 0 to LC do
      AVals[i]:=Vals[i + I0];
      //copy lower half or Vals into temporary array AVals

    k := I0;
    i := 0;
    j := J0;
    while ((i <= LC) and (j <= J1)) do
    if (AVals[i] < Vals[j]) then begin
      Vals[k] := AVals[i];
      inc(i);
      inc(k);
    end else  if (AVals[i] > Vals[j]) then begin
      Vals[k]:=Vals[j];
      inc(k);
      inc(j);
    end else begin //duplicate
      Vals[k] := AVals[i];
      inc(i);
      inc(j);
      inc(k);
    end;

    //copy the rest
    while i <= LC do begin
      Vals[k] := AVals[i];
      inc(i);
      inc(k);
    end;

    if k <> j then
      while j <= J1 do begin
        Vals[k]:=Vals[j];
        inc(k);
        inc(j);
      end;

    Result := k - 1;
  end;

 //returns index of the last valid element

  function PerformMergeSort(ALo, AHi:Integer): Integer; //returns
  var
    AMid, I1, J1:Integer;
  begin

  //It would be wise to use Insertion Sort when (AHi - ALo) is small (about 32-100)
    if (ALo < AHi) then
    begin
      AMid:=(ALo + AHi) shr 1;
      I1 := PerformMergeSort(ALo, AMid);
      J1 := PerformMergeSort(AMid + 1, AHi);
      Result := Merge(ALo, I1, AMid + 1, J1);
    end else
      Result := ALo;
  end;

begin
  SetLength(AVals, Length(Vals) div 2 + 1);
  Result := 1 + PerformMergeSort(0, High(Vals));
end;
```

here is my understanding with very small modification:

```
function MergeSortRemoveDuplicates(var Vals: array of Integer):Integer;
var
  AVals: array of Integer;

   //returns index of the last valid element
  function Merge(I0, I1, J0, J1: Integer):Integer;
  var
    i, j, k, LC:Integer;
  begin
    // difference between mid-point on leftside
    // between low(Original_array) and midpoint(true Original_array midpoint)
    // subtracting I0 which is Low(Original_array)
    // or here equals zero(0)
    // so LC is quarter point in Original_array??
    LC := I1 - I0;

    // here we walk from begining of array
    // and copy the elements between zero and LC
    // this is funny call that Vals[i + I0] like 0 + 0
    // then 1 + 0 and so on. I guess this guarantees if we are
    // starting from non-zero based array??
    for i := 0 to LC do
      AVals[i]:=Vals[i + I0];


    // k equal low(Original_array)
    k := I0;

    // I will be our zero based counter element
    i := 0;

    // J will be (midpoint + 1) or
    // begining element of right side of array
    j := J0;

    // while we look at Copy_array elements
    // between first element (low(Copy_array)
    // and original_array from midpoint + 1 to high(Original_array)
    // we start to sort it
    while ((i <= LC) and (j <= J1)) do

    // if the value at Copy_array is smaller than the Original_array
    // we move it to begining of Original_array
    // remember position K is first element
    if (AVals[i] < Vals[j]) then begin
      Vals[k] := AVals[i];

      // move to next element in Copy_array
      inc(i);

      // move to next element in Original_array
      inc(k);

    // if the value at copy_array is larger
    // then we move smaller value from J Original_array (J is midpoint+1)
    // to position K original_array (K now is the lower part of ) Original_array)
    end else  if (AVals[i] > Vals[j]) then begin
      Vals[k]:=Vals[j];

      //move K to the next element in Original_array
      inc(k);

      // move j to next element in Original_array
      inc(j);

    // if the value in Original_array is equal to the element in Copy_array
    // do nothing and count everything up
    // so we end up with one copy from duplicate and disregard the rest
    end else begin //duplicate
      Vals[k] := AVals[i];
      inc(i);
      inc(j);
      inc(k);
    end;

    //copy the rest
    while i <= LC do begin
      Vals[k] := AVals[i];
      inc(i);
      inc(k);
    end;

    // if the counters do not endup at the same element
    // this means we have some that maybe leftover on
    // the right side of the Original_array.
    // This explains why K does not equal J : there are still elements left over
    // then copy them to Original_array
    // starting at position K.
    if k <> j then
      while j <= J1 do begin
        Vals[k]:=Vals[j];
        inc(k);
        inc(j);
      end;

    // why K - 1?
    // function needs result so return will be null if called
    // I don't understand this part
    Result := k - 1;
  end;

 //returns index of the last valid element

  function PerformMergeSort(ALo, AHi:Integer): Integer; //returns
  var
    AMid, I1, J1:Integer;
  begin

  //It would be wise to use Insertion Sort when (AHi - ALo) is small (about 32-100)
    if (ALo < AHi) then
    begin
      AMid:=(ALo + AHi) shr 1;    // midpoint
      I1 := PerformMergeSort(ALo, AMid);  //recursive call I1 is a data point on the left
      J1 := PerformMergeSort(AMid + 1, AHi);  // recursive call I1 is a data point on the right
      Result := Merge(ALo, I1, AMid + 1, J1);
    end else
      Result := ALo;
  end;

begin
  // test if array is even then we can split nicely down middle
  if Length(Vals) mod 2 = 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(AVals, Length(Vals) shr 1);
    Result := PerformMergeSort(0, High(Vals));
  end
  else
  //array is odd let us add 1 to it and make it even
  // shr 1 is essentially dividing by 2 but doing it on the bit level
  begin
    SetLength(AVals, (Length(Vals) + 1) shr 1);
    Result := PerformMergeSort(0, High(Vals));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You might enjoy [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaqR3G_NVoo&feature=related) dancing example of merge sort :)

Comment: nice and I liked they used 10 as it ends up 2 + 3 on the second split. :)

Comment: @LURD, nice merge sort example, however I can't imagine this speed in production environment :-)

Comment: This video maybe [helpful](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INHF_5RIxTE) but start @3:10 as it has more than one sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my modification of code presented by author, intended to remove duplicates during the sorting. Some explanations:

External function:

1. We should provide buffer (AVals) to store half of the initial aray. *Length(Vals) div 2 + 1* provides enough space for odd- and even-sized arrays without unnecessary complication. Better value (for all cases): **Length(Vals + 1) div 2**
2. Internal procedure PerformMergeSort returns **index** of the last valid element, but external procedure returns **count** of valid elements (it was commented in the cited topic), so I use (1 + PerformMergeSort()).

   Reasons: internally we have to work with indexes, but end user of this procedure should know new array length.

Internal function PerformMergeSort:

It takes start and end indexes of array chunk, sorting this chunk and returns index of the last valid element. After recursive calls we have this situation.
Invariant: both chunks are sorted, they don't contain duplicates, non-zero length of left segment

```
*****ACDEFG****BCDEGHILM******
     ^    ^    ^       ^
     |    |    |       |
     Alo  I1   AMid+1  J1 
     I0   I1   J0      J1  //as named in Merge 
     \____/
       LC+1 elements
```

And after merging:

```
*****ABCDEFGHILM**************
     ^         ^^
     |         ||__k
     |         | 
     Alo       Result
```

Internal function Merge:

Use provided example, pen and paper, step through merging, see how it works.

Concerning to copy cycle: we copy (LC+1) elements to temporary buffer AVals, using start segment of AVals (always starting from 0) and proper segment of the main array (starting from I0, it is usually non-zero)

Comment: thank you for the explanation. What was the reason for this:            `for i := 0 to LC do
      AVals[i]:=Vals[i + I0];` I mean the I0 part? as it would always be adding a zero on a zero based array?

Comment: Try to explain, look at addition.