# Merge sort remove duplicates

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to sort an array via **merge sort**, and while sorting, remove elements that I have deemed equal.  I am recursively calling merge sort and then merging.

I get to this point and find that `a` and `c` are **duplicates**.

```
a b | c d
```

I determine which one I want based on certain criteria and I pick c. I increment the right hand counter and and the left hand counter and compare b and d.  Say I pick d, then I pick b. I want my final list to only have the elements

```
c d b
```

However, what is happening is on the next recursive call, `start` and `end` are 0 and 3 so d is listed twice in the array on the next call.  The array that the merge procedure works with is:

```
c d b d
```

Here is the code.  Thanks in advance.

```
private static void merge(int[] data, int start, int mid, int end)
{
    int firstCopied=0;
    int secondCopied=0;
    int index=0;
    int length=end-start+1;

    int[] temp = new int[end-start+1];
    int firstSize=mid-start+1;
    int secondSize=end-mid;

    while(firstCopied < firstSize && secondCopied < secondSize)
    {
        if(data[start+firstCopied] < data[mid+1+secondCopied])
        {
            temp[index++] = data[start+firstCopied];
            firstCopied++;
        }

        else if(data[start+firstCopied] > data[mid+1+secondCopied])
        {
            temp[index++] = data[mid+1+secondCopied];
            secondCopied++;
        }

        else if(data[start+firstCopied]==data[mid+1+secondCopied])
        {
            boolean result = PickOne();

            if(result)
            {
                temp[index++] = data[start+firstCopied];
            }
            else
            {
                temp[index++] = data[mid+1+secondCopied];
            }

            firstCopied++;
            secondCopied++;
            length--;
        }
    }
    while(firstCopied < firstSize)
    {
        temp[index++] = data[start+firstCopied];
        firstCopied++;
    }

    while(secondCopied < secondSize)
    {
        temp[index++] = data[mid+1+secondCopied];
        secondCopied++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        data[start+i]=temp[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: What does `PickOne()` do?

Comment: It seems to me that mergesort is already complicated enough without intertwining special-purpose code to delete duplicates into it. I'd suggest two separate functions: first mergesort the data, then delete the duplicates, which will presumably be sequential in the sorted data and therefore easy to find.

Comment: You've tagged this C and C++ but `private static void ...` and `int[] temp = new int[end-start+1];` indicate that this is another language. Which language are you actually using?

Comment: working example of Mergesort modification with duplicate deleting (in Delphi): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673633/delphi-mergesort-for-string-arrays/12677518#12677518

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I tagged it as mergeSort, but someone changed it. This language is Java. I have already written code to post process the array but I was told to remove dups while merging.  I haven't seen any code for this, just vague suggestions to "not add the duplicates to your list". That is not the problem, the problem is that mergeSort is recursive and you can't change the "chunk" of the array it is considering at each step. There has to be way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `merge` conceptually changes the length of the array. But there is no code to actually truncate `data`. I suggest you return `length` (instead of `void`) and use some final postprocessing step to either truncate the data to the final length, or at least avoid printing those past-the-end elements.

Answer (score 1):

The philosophy of the C++ Standard Library is to use algorithms that do **one thing well**. It's best to follow that approach since it will lead to more reusable code.

E.g. here's a mergesort sketch followed by a call to `std::unique`

```
template<typename BiDirIt>
void merge_sort(BiDirIt first, BiDirIt last)
{
    auto const N = std::distance(first, last);
    if (N < 2) return;

    // sort each part individually, then merge back in-place
    auto middle = first + N / 2;
    merge_sort(first, middle);
    merge_sort(middle, last);
    std::inplace_merge(first, middle, last);
}    

int data[] = { /* your data */ };
merge_sort(std::begin(data), std::end(data));

auto it = std::unique(std::begin(data), std::end(data));
for (auto ut = std::begin(data); ut != it; ++ut) {
    // process unique data
}
```

If your data was in a `std::vector` instead of a C-array, you could call `v.erase(v.begin(), it);` to actually erase the non-unique data as well.

Comment: I'm surprised you use custom code for sorting and rely on defaults for removal of unique elements. I'd rather do it the other way round, since `std::sort` or `std::stable_sort` should give the same result, but deliberately choosing between two equal elements (like `PickOne` presumably does) isn't part of the job for [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: @MvG I wrote a custom `merge_sort` to show how easy it would be to write it with recursion + `std::inplace_merge`, not as a replacement for `std::stable_sort`. Perhaps I glossed over the `PickOne` selection criterion, but the main point of my answer was to let one algorithm do one thing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the elements in [start, mid] and [mid + 1, end] is sorted and unique, first.
Otherwise, duplicates will exists after your code run.